# How to extract digital signatures from PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

It seems like it should be such an easy task - or at least previously asked somewhere, but I can't find anything useful. Is there a command line utility that will give information about digitally signed pdf's?

So far, I've tried only PLOP DS, but it gives the following:

```
Signatures: 1
    invisible signature field 'sigField': signed
```

Is there anything else to try?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), its a library for creating and manipulation Pdfs in Java. You can find some useful examples about signatures here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222 (see `verifySignatures()` method)

Comment: Yeah, I know about iText. We use PHP tho.